# Why use getTag/setTag when we can do the same with static variable

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

We know when we use `ViewHolder` pattern in list/grid view, we use setTag/getTag to get information. But here in my code if I replace this via simple static ViewHolder, it works fine and displayed image correctly. So, what's the use of `getTag()/setTag()`?

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
   if(convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
      ViewHolder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
   }
   // ....
   // ... attach image here. Via library or directly.
   // As an example I'm using Picasso
   Picasso.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[pos]).into(ViewHolder.image);

   return convertView;
}

// static ViewHolder pattern.
private final static ViewHolder {
  static final ImageView image;
}

private int mThumbIds[] = {
 R.drawable.sample1, R.drawable.sample2 // etc...
};
```

Here's the xml in case you need:
**card_view.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Show where you're actually getting the image out of the ViewHolder, and it will become obvious to you.

Comment: This is fine if all the items in your listview use the same image. However the usual usage pattern is to create a new ViewHolder object for each listview item, and call setTag on the listview item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But here in my code if I replace this via simple static ViewHolder, it works fine

No, it does not.

First, you are leaking memory like a sieve.

Second, as soon as the user scrolls, your approach will break, as you will start updating the wrong `ImageView`. Your code is relying upon the fact that rows never get recycled, which will only be true if either your `ListView`/`GridView` does not require much scrolling, or if you have a seriously messed-up adapter that is trying to avoid view recycling altogether.

Comment: I checked the code by putting lots of images (from `res/drawable`). It works fine with scrolling. With a 200x200 image, memory consume max 25MB. Can you explain how I put wrong `ImageView` ? How android stores different ID's for same `ImageView` and where?

Comment: @AshishRawat: "It works fine with scrolling" -- not the code that you have in your question. If `convertView` is not `null`, you will use whatever `ImageView` happened to be used the last time `convertView` was `null` and you updated your static data member.

Comment: Ok, I understand It'll use last `ImageView` of the `convertView` before `ListView` recycle. But I'm inflating the `card_view.xml` not the image with the `ListView`. So, I think it doesn't matter if static data member use last `ImageView` because android store only one instance of that Image (not `card_view.xml`).

Comment: @AshishRawat: "But I'm inflating the card_view.xml not the image with the ListView" -- `card_view.xml` contains an `ImageView`. Every time you inflate the layout, you get a *new* `ImageView`. "android store only one instance of that Image" -- if by "Image" you mean `ImageView`, there will be one `ImageView` per row in the list or cell in the grid (plus perhaps a few more, to enable rapid reaction to scroll events).

Comment: I found the problem. That's not a memory problem. You're right single instance of `ImageView` affect recycling in `ListView`. I put 300+ images with a repetitions and did scrolling slowly. I saw that images changes randomly as the list goes off the screen.

Comment: @AshishRawat: "That's not a memory problem" -- it is, insofar as so long as `image` is not `null`, you are leaking the `ImageView`, its `Activity`, and everything else reachable from all of that. Even if the activity is destroyed (e.g., user presses BACK), you still hold a reference to it, unless you remember to `null` it out. "I saw that images changes randomly as the list goes off the screen" -- yes, that is the classic symptom of row recycling problems.

Comment: Now I understand slightly, yes it's a memory leak because I'm holding a reference to static members if after the `Activity` destroys. I compared it with `Item 6` of `Effective Java`. Thanks :)